# Parallels Plesk + IIS7 asp.net 4.0 error: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-4.0, application-pool, plesk

I'm using a godaddy VPS with parallels plesk. Since my application is asp.net 4.0 I get the error:

```
"Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'
```

I realize it's because the application pools are set to asp.net 2.0, which I can't change in plesk, so I remote connect to my server, open IIS7, go into my application pools and set all of them to asp.net 4.0, but then I get this detailed error: (caused by changing plesk(default)(2.0)(pool) to 4.0)

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by
the static file handler.

Most Likely Causes:

•The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the
static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the
request will map to a different handler.
```

How can I get my asp.net 4.0 web application to run properly? There must be a decent way to get my asp.net application to run with parallels plesk. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?  Mine is about to be uninstall plesk.  I have never had so much trouble setting up a server in my life.

Comment: I uninstalled it shortly after, that thing was a pain

Answer (score 0):

Getting the following error when you deploy your first asp.net 4.0 website:

Unrecognized attribute ‘targetFramework’. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

is most likely because of either of 2 reasons:
1. You installed the .net 4.0 bits after IIS was set up, resulting in the wrong version of the .NET framework beeing registered with IIS.

Most often the above results in conflicting versions of the framework, and so the easiest way of solving this is to re-register the .NET extensions with IIS using the aspnet_regiss tool. Make sure you run it from an elevated command prompt and that you use the correct version (in the v4.xx folder that is, not the v2.xx one). On my dev machine this tool is located in:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

and you run it with the -iru flags like so:

aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
2. You haven’t set the framework of the IIS application to the correct version of .NET (4.0 that is)

Change this using either the IIS Manager or the command line. In IIS Manager you select ‘Application Pools’, click the Application you’ve pointed you site to use, select ‘Basic Settings’ in the ‘Actions’ pane and change the ‘.NET framework version’.

This post over at MSDN should also be of great help. Gotta love Microsoft’s documentation!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478(VS.100).aspx